# Will ipconfig /all display the correct dns ip's being used by my router if I have manually configured my router to use a specific dns

Tags: router, dns

I basically want to know if ipconfig is just looking at my pc settings or is somehow able to tell me what is going on in my router. Or is the only way to know for sure what is setup on my router to go through the router administration?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

IPCONFIG is just about what's going on in your computer. It won't tell you anything about your router and what it's up to (except for maybe, it's IP address).

Answer (score 0):

If you have your PC set to pick up your DNS server address automaticaly then `ipconfig /all` **will** show the DNS set in your router if you have changed it manually.

For instance, on my PC `ipconfig /all` shows the router set OpenDNS server (208.67.222.222) since the PC is set as shown below.

You can find your IPv4 settings via (in Windows 7):
`Control Panel > Network and Sharing Center > Local area connection > Properties > Internet Protocol Version 4 >`
[image]

Comment: This is correct if the router is also providing DHCP. There is no requirement that the router do this, but in small networks it is *probably* the case. In larger networks it probably won't be.